# Item Control Modified Not Displayed Properly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sorting, observable

I have item control which is bind with List. When I tried to add an item in that list it is not reflected in the item control (UI). But when replaced the Observable Collection instead of list It is perfectly worked what is the reason on that Could you please help me?

Is it any way sort the observable collection directly?

Comment: That's why there is an ObservableCollection class, notify the UI.

Comment: You muse use an ObservableCollection. If you want to sort the items in an observable collection, create a new observablecollection: `MyCollectionProp = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>(MyCollectionProp.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty));` The setter for `MyCollectionProp` must raise PropertyChanged in its setter.

Comment: Have you investigated CollectionViewSource to solve your sorting issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the `ObservableCollection<T>` class implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raises the `CollectionChanged` event whenever an item is added and removed. This is required for the UI to be updated automatically. A `List<T>` does not implement this interface.

> Is it any way sort the observable collection directly?

The easiest way to sort the source collection itself is to do pass a sorted `IEnumerable` to it when you create it:

```
this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<Type>(list.OrderBy(x => x.Property));
```

It has no built-in `Sort` method that sorts the items internally.